# Sonata Admin Bundle for Symfony 2, Many-To-Many Relation

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I would like to use the Sonata Admin bundle to manage my Blog model.

I have a post entity with a Many-to-many relation to tags.

In my post admin class I defined the field for the tags like so:

```
->add('tags', 'sonata_type_model', array('expanded' => true, 'multiple' => true))
```

Now I can add a new tag which works fine but what I need is a list of the already existing tags. How can I achieve this?

Comment: "of the existing tags in the tags entity" ?

Comment: Yes that doesn't make any sense ;-). I mean a list of the tags which are already in the database.

Comment: Hum normally it should render checkboxes for each tags. Did you have a __toString method in Tag entity ?